# How to decrease the space between these form input fields (Bootstrap 4)?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I've tried it with:

```
.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

This is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santosonit/z8o97jre/5/#&togetherjs=62HN3GE1Nq)

Appreciate your help!

Comment: You mean you are missing `!important`?

Comment: Just saw you doing that! Thank you, @ulou!!